# ADO Query -- display all changes/updates to user story or task in a 24 hour period using a query

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I would like to run a query in ADO that reports on all changes to the user stories and tasks.  The query I am using currently only shows the last update.  I know the data is there because it is in the history but I can't figure out how to show all updates in a 24 hour period.

Anyone else ever had this need or have an idea how to resolve?